Question: optical vector analyzer principle
i have a question about optical vector analyzer
i'm wondering about how to get the phase response of optical passive component.
In [Advances in swept-wavelength interferometry for precision measurements] paper

above equation becomes following equation with signal processing procedure(i uploaded this)


can you explain about this? i don't understand why the real value becomes complex value..

for step (C) check out the Hilbert transform https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform

The complex notation is just a convenience. We could use a single real valued periodic function and a real valued phase, but it's easier to go with the complex representation.
